# STI and preload relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, preload, sti

I have next models:

```
class User  < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Customer < User
  has_many :orders, foreign_key: 'customer_id', dependent: :destroy
end

class Translator < User
 has_many :orders, foreign_key: 'translator_id'
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, class_name: "Customer"
  belongs_to :translator , class_name: "Translator"
end
```

And I have an issue when I try to load orders with translator and customer , like this:

```
Order.eager_load(:vox_logs,:customer, :translator)
```

In this case customer will be loaded fine but translator not:

```
order.translator = nil
order.translator_id = 123
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT:
I added console output for more clear (it's from a order's function):

```
(byebug) translator
nil
(byebug) translator_id
637
(byebug) Translator.find translator_id
Translator Load (70.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE       ((users.roles_mask & 4) > 0) AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 637]]

<Translator id: 637, email: nil, first_name: nil, middle_name: nil,
last_name: nil, native_language: "fr", country: "RU", city: "Липецк"...
```

Comment: Do you have a record in your `translators` table with an ID of `123`? It looks like an orphaned association.

Comment: Odd. Have you defined a `translator` method on Order that's overwriting it? We might need to see the full class.

Comment: @tombeynon, No I haven't. I am sure problem in eager_load, because if I move translator on first position and customer on second - all turn around: translator will work, customer not.